# Does review count skipped questions?

Tags: support, review-queues

If I am reviewing 10 questions and for ex: in 2 questions I am not sure that if it **needs improvement** or **looks OK** or **need flag** so finally I click on **"Skip" option**. So it means during review I have done "skip" for 2 question. Does Stack Overflow system count those skipped questions as reviewed? by me?

I mean as per above scenario what system will consider? I have reviewed 10 questions or 8??

Comment: Ask yourself this: Did you actually do anything with that question, when you clicked "Skip"? (Nope)

Comment: You should also be able to see the review count in your Badge Progress.

Comment: @Cerbrus - Ok..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> Does Stack Overflow system count those skipped questions as reviewed?
>   by me?

No.

Skipped reviews do not count towards your number reviewed counter.

Skipped reviews do make it so that you don't receive that review again. So if you click skip, you will not see that same review again, unless you click the back button or go to the review url directly for that review. It also adjusts the count for you on the number of available reviews. For example, if the queue shows 18 reviews waiting, and you go and skip all 18, then it will show 0 reviews waiting for you when you go back to the review page (*if caching isn't involved of course*).